# Jquery submit on image

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-selectors

I have a list of images where I want users to be able to click on an image and it submits the data with jquery. So given several images, a user can click on any one of them and it automatically submits to a jquery landing page with the id of the image that the person has chosen. Here is my attempt at the code using a list as images..

```
<ul>
<li><img id='1' src='/img1.png'></li>
<li><img id='2' src='/img2.png'></li>
<li><img id='3' src='/img3.png'></li>
</ul>

$(function()
{
     $('#img').click(function()
     {
       var datastring = //either 1,2,3 corresponding to image id
       $.ajax({   
       type: "POST",   
       url: "process.php",   
       data: dataString,   
       success: function() {   
          alert('Image Submitted')  
       }      
     });   
}
```

Comment: you'll get that as part of this, in your case it would be:
    var id= $(this).attr('id');

Comment: That `#` shouldn't be there for a start.

Comment: Please read up on valid html ID's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @paislee: good advice, IDs are not allowed to start with numbers; if you need custom properties as alternative, use HTML5's enhanced tag attributes:
http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Basically spoken, just write it like: <img data-node="1" src="/img1.png"/> and access the node's value using $(this).attr('data-node')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    var datastring = $(this).prop('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
            alert('Image Submitted')
        }
    });
});​
```

**P.S.** The easiest way to see the difference between `.attr` and `.prop` is the following example:

```
<input blah="hello" />
```

1. **`$('input').attr('blah')`**: returns `'hello'` as expected. No suprises here.
2. **`$('input').prop('blah')`**: returns `undefined` -- because it's trying to do `[HTMLInputElement].blah` -- and no such property on that DOM object exists. It only exists in the scope as an attribute of that element i.e. `[HTMLInputElement].getAttribute('blah')`

So, a property is in the DOM; an attribute is in the HTML that is parsed into the DOM. So use prop !

Answer (score 0):

The complete version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').click(function()
  {
   var datastring = $(this).attr('id'); // or simply $(this).id;
   $.ajax({   
   type: "POST",   
   url: "process.php",   
   data: dataString,   
   success: function() {   
      alert('Image Submitted')  
  }      
 });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick look suggests changing these lines:

```
$('#img').click(function()
 {
   var datastring = //either 1,2,3 corresponding to image id
```

to this:

```
 $('img').click(function()
 {
   var datastring = $(this).attr('id');
```

So we've lost the `#` since you're not looking for an id. And we've added retrieving the id.

For this part see http://jsfiddle.net/tAH7F/